# How to remove the border on boostrap accordion

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-accordion

I am building a dashboard, the sidebar should have a dropdown list, I am finding it difficult using boostrap accordion. I want to remove the border that came with the accordion, here is my code:

```
<li className='sidebar-list-item w-100 border-0'>
                <Accordion className="border-0">
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                        <Accordion.Header><i className="fas fa-chart-bar text-green"></i> <span>L T S</span></Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                            <p>New LTS</p>
                            <p>My LTS</p>
                        </Accordion.Body>
                        </Accordion.Item>
                </Accordion>
            </li>`enter code here`
```

Comment: The border is on the accordion item

Comment: Thanks 

But now the Header text is white and background of the accordion is white too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your CSS file.

Using an external CSS file (e.g., App.css)

App.css

```
.sidebar-list-item .accordion-button {
  border: none; /* Remove the border */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work

Comment: Please check that the CSS file has been imported correctly? because this is really working.